# Is this a valid question? Solve inequality $\vert \frac{a}{x-b} > c \vert$?

Tags: inequality

Is the question valid or was it supposed to be $\vert \frac{a}{x-b} \vert > c$? In case it is correct, how do I approach this?

Comment: The question in your title is not valid, It does make sense to take the absolute value of an inequality, which is either true or false. To tackle the inequality $\vert \frac{a}{x-b} \vert > c$, think about when the quantity inside the absolute value is positive/negative, and use the definition of $\vert\cdot\vert$.

Comment: Let me add to @stange's comment, that on the other hand anything can be valid, if the author re-defined notations, and therefore they don't mean what they usually do. We are assuming that it means as usual: absolute value.

Comment: @stange Sorry for being unclear. I meant if the original was correct then how would I solve it. Seems like everyone that I have asked so far agree that it it indeed invalid and I should have been in the form of |a/x-b| > c.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó indeed all the symbols mean what they usually do, and seems like this was just a printing error.